# Search alghoritm in C

Tags: c, search

I need to write a program that looks for a file according to the path provided.
I have no idea how to do this, a simple dir command does not work.

Please help.

My sample code to delete a directory by path.

```
void delete_file(){
int a;
int check;
char *dirname;
dirname=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
system("cls");
printf("\nUSUWANIE KATALOGU\n");
printf("\nPodaj nazwe oraz  sciezke: np(C:/name): ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(dirname);
check = rmdir(dirname);

if (!check)
    printf("\nFolder zostal usuniety\n");

else
{
    printf("\nNie mozna usunac folderu\n");
}
printf("Chcesz powrocic do menu glownego? 1-Tak/0-Nie: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
if(a==1){
    main();
}
else{
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not going to sugarcoat this. Obviously none of this is correct for search for a file. But even for the task it was intended (deleting a folder), it does nearly everything wrong. Not checking allocation success, invoking `fflush` on an input stream, using `gets` (a function so evil it was removed from the standard library), failure to check *all* input operations for success/failure and act accordingly, invoking `main()` from *anywhere*, and the memory leak of `dirname` (not a huge deal if the program is terminating, but a terrible practice nonetheless).  *All* of those should be addressed.

Comment: I do not understand you say you want to do a search/delete a file but use _rmdir_

Comment: I wrote that I give this code as an example (this is one of the functions from my program).

Comment: Ok,i changed gets() to scanf(%c) but I had to use flush (stdin), otherwise the program doesn't give me the path and file name to delete - it goes straight away.